# Why would calling ReadFile() return error code 1?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, io, driver

Currently, I am attempting to access my driver and read data from it. According to the MSDN, one way to do this is by calling the `CreateFile`, passing in the file path of the PDO for the driver and using `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` functions to read from and write to the file respectively.

My code is simple:

```
int main()
{

    CHAR readBuffer[32];

    HANDLE handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LPDWORD bytesRead = 0;

    // File path to my custom device. Valid path.
    LPCWSTR filePath = L"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\00000010";

    // Obtain handle to Device File for custom driver
    handle = CreateFile(filePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);

    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "File Exists! \n";
    }
    else
        cout << "Cannot Open File with error: " << error << " \n";

    // Call to CreateFile succeeds.
    // Below here is where I have the issues----------------------------------

    cout << "\nAttempting to Read 32 bits from opened file... \n";

    // Attempt to Read data from the device 
    BOOL success = ReadFile(handle, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), bytesRead, NULL);
    if (success)
        cout << "Read File status is: " << success << " \n";
    else
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        cout << "Read File status is: " << success << " with error code: " << error << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As stated in the code, the `CreateFile` function succeeds at opening the PDO that is relative to the driver. For the last output line, I am getting:

```
Read File status is: 0 with error code: 1
```

This means that the `ReadFile` function is not completing properly. On the MSDN, the error code 1 is `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` and, in this case, it is in regards to the call to `ReadFile`.

I understand there are "better" ways of doing this, however the way I am attempting to access my driver should be the simplest way. In addition, I have tried to run it in "Administrator Mode" like people suggested in other similar posts, but to no avail.

What in my call to the `ReadFile` function could cause this? Additionally, what causes this vague error (other than the function being invalid)?

Thank you in advance for your time and help with this issue.

Comment: I somehow doubt that the code you show is the code you're running. Mainly because the code in your question will not build. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: The second to last argument `lpNumberOfBytesRead` isn't optional (must not be null). From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467): "This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL."

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  The only actual error was the fact that I capitalized the 'M' in "Main".

Comment: @user786653 Same error still. Editing post.

Comment: `LPDWORD bytesRead = 0;` ... `bytesRead,` ... it's stil `NULL`. Try`DWORD bytesRead = 0;` .... `&bytesRead` instead.

Comment: @user786653 I thought of that too, but the variations of `bytesRead` all give me an error code of 1.

Comment: you got `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST` i think (it converted to 1) - are driver implemented IRP_MJ_READ ? then you use FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING - so you must read aligned o sector size - are 32 bytes - multiple your sector size ? and are you support cache ? if no - what sense in this flag ? and post not converted win32 errors but NTSTATUS values

Comment: I agree with RbMm.  The problem is most likely in the driver, not the application.  (Assuming you've fixed the problem with the bytesRead argument.)

Comment: @RbMm Oh dang! I forgot about registering/implementing IRP_MJ_READ. I'll try it right away and let you know if that fixes things.

Comment: @JakeSamz - if you not register IRP_MJ_READ in driver object of course will be called default handler, which return STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST. and for what you use FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING ? (just interesting)